How to perform a LEFT JOIN in Supabase JS?
I want to perform the following SQL query with the Supabase JS Client Library:
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN follows f
  ON u.id = f.followed_id
  AND f.follower_id = :some_id
WHERE f.followed_id IS NULL
  AND u.id != :some_id

Is the only way to achieve this by creating an RPC and calling it from the JS client?

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/joins-and-nesting or you can create a function for that
